# Error when executing command

Tags: linux, bash, simulation

This was my input while trying to minimize my protein structure in AMBER.

```
$sander -O -i Min.in -o Min.out -p prmtop -c inpcrd -r Min.rst
```

and the output said

```
-bash: -O: command not found
```

This has to be the syntax. Please help.

Comment: What is `$sander` ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your problem is that variable `sander` is not defined or have empty value. You can check this by exec on of those commands:

```
echo $sander
set|grep sander
```